# JS/TS easy way of mapping short version of string to display friendly one

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say i get data from my backend that are for example one of

```
A,
B,
C,
D
```

But there are really like 20 letters I can get here and I know it will always be one of these letters coming. and for example I would like to map so when I get an `A` from the backend I display `Alfa` and if I get an `B` I display `Beta` etc. A nice way of doing this without creating a massive switch?

Trying with an const like

```
export const Test = {
  SWE: 'Sweden',
  DK: 'Denmark'
}
```

And then doing

```
Test[countrycode]
```

It cant build because `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ SWE: string; DK: string;`

The reason I don't have '' around the first part is because prettier demands it to be like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps.

1. Make an interface for the mapping variable so that typescript won't throw out `Element is implicitly any...` problem
2. Put your type behind your variable by using `:`

```
interface TestType = {
   [key: string]: string  //meaning as long as the key is string, it is ok for the key. Therefore, you won't need to hardcode every country code to your interface
}

export const test: TestType = {
  "SWE": "Sweden",
  "DK": "Denmark", 
  ...
}

//actual usage
const res = //from backend, res is the letter

console.log(test[res])
```

Comment: Hey! i tried this solution but i ran into a problem. Could you have a look on my edit? :)

Comment: @novafluff I have updated my answer. The problem is that you don't specify the type. Adding interface should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you only need to create a map with the values that you need to get, so basically you can loop and get the desired values.

```js
const map = {
  'a': 'alpha',
  'b': 'beta',
  'g': 'gamma'
}

const response = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g']

const result = response.map(r => map[r] || r);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//var letterFromBackend = "A";
var shortStringsMap = {"A":"Alfa", "B": "Beta"};
return shortStringsMap[letterFromBackend] || letterFromBackend;

//better not case sensitive
var shortStringsMap = {"a":"Alfa", "b": "Beta"};
return shortStringsMap[letterFromBackend.toLowerCase()] || letterFromBackend;
```